# How can I tell if someone is trying to hack port 8333?

Tags: blockchain, security

I am experimenting with leaving a public replica of the Bitcoin chain on the internet.  In doing so I'm actively monitoring the debug output so I can get a sense of what is happening with the inbound connections.

How can I tell what the clients are doing and respond appropriately?

Under what criteria should I block a port to an IP address, subnet, etc?

Comment: The client shouldn't rely on any special firewalling or packet inspection.  It should be secure against all hack attempts.

If you are concerned about there being a denial of service you can disable incoming connections and only support outgoing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for ways to improve the client's protections against flaws?

Here's a list of its current protections:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Weaknesses#Denial_of_Service_.28DoS.29_attacks